# Wordpress Cron Scheduler is running function multiple times in succession

Tags: wordpress, cron, wordpress-plugin-creation

I have a plugin that allows a user to set a date to schedule a set of emails to get out. When they save the settings it creates a scheduled task set up to run weekly. That all seems to work as expected. I can view the scheduled job to run using the WP Crontrol plugin.

The problem is that once it hits its countdown, it seems to run the function around 8 times or so instead of just once, so it sends out 15 emails (one for each location) x 8.

I'm trying to figure out if i set this up wrong. I can post my construct and the method it calls.

`suddath_send_reviews` is the hook

```
public function __construct( $plugin_name, $version ) {
    
    $this->plugin_name = $plugin_name;
    $this->version     = $version;
    
    // Actions
    add_action( 'init', [ $this, 'create_reviews_location_taxonomy' ], 0 );
    add_action( 'admin_menu', [ $this, 'create_admin_menu_item' ] );
    add_action( 'admin_init', [ $this, 'update_general_settings' ] );
    // add_action( 'admin_menu', [ $this, 'add_tax_to_reviews' ] );
    add_action( 'site-reviews/review/created', [ $this, 'add_location_to_submitted_review' ], 10, 2 );
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_send_email_data', [ $this, 'get_reviews_one_location' ] );
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_send_email_data', [ $this, 'get_reviews_one_location' ] );
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_send_all_email_data', [ $this, 'get_reviews_all_locations' ] );
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_send_all_email_data', [ $this, 'get_reviews_all_locations' ] );
    add_action( 'admin_notices', [ $this, 'rr_updated_admin_notice' ]);
    add_action( 'acf/init', [ $this, 'rr_acf_add_local_field_groups' ]);
    
    // Filters
    add_filter( 'cron_schedules', [ $this, 'add_weekly_cron_schedule' ] );
    
    // get day/time options
    $day   = get_option( 'send_review_day' );
    $time  = get_option( 'send_review_time' );
    $am_pm = get_option( 'send_review_nightday' );
    
    wp_unschedule_hook( 'suddath_send_reviews' );
    
    // run scheduler based on options selected on plugin admin page
    // If it hasnt already been scheduled 
    if (
        !empty( $day ) &&
        !empty( $time ) &&
        !empty( $am_pm )
        ):
        $hour = explode( ':', $time )[0];
        if ( $am_pm === 'pm' ):
            $hour += 12;
            $time = "$hour:00:00";
        endif;
        
        // Add 5 hours  because cron defaults to UTC -5
        if ( ! wp_next_scheduled( 'suddath_send_reviews' ) ):
            
            wp_schedule_event(
                strtotime( "this $day $time +5 hours" ),
                get_option( 'send_review_frequency' ),
                'suddath_send_reviews'
            );
            // else:
                //  wp_unschedule_hook( 'suddath_send_reviews' );
                //  wp_schedule_event(
                    //      strtotime( "this $day $time +5 hours" ),
                    //      get_option( 'send_review_frequency' ),
                    //      'suddath_send_reviews'
                    //  );
        endif;
        add_action( 'suddath_send_reviews', [ $this, 'get_reviews_all_locations' ] );
    endif;
}

public function get_reviews_all_locations(){
    $locations   = $this->get_review_locations_list();
    
    foreach( $locations as $location ):
        $assigned_to = get_field( 'location_id', $location );
        
        if( $assigned_to ):
            $args             = $this->get_review_args( $assigned_to );
            $location_reviews = $this->get_location_reviews( $args );
        endif;
        
        $this->create_html_template( $location, $location_reviews );
        $pdf_location = plugin_dir_path( __DIR__ ) . 'admin/partials/pdf.html';
        $this->generate_market_pdf( $pdf_location, $location->slug, $location->name );
    endforeach;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**There are multiple possibilities for such issue.**

Try to check whether are there any schedule event attached to your function or not. This happen if we change the time of event for testing and forget to unschedule an event.

Second is it may be possible that your hook is getting executed more than once. You can prevent execution of hook more than once on your specific code using `did_action`.

```
if( did_action(suddath_send_reviews) < 1){ //Whenver this hook trigger, execute only once
    add_action( 'suddath_send_reviews', [ $this, 'get_reviews_all_locations' ] );
}
```